# Do different tabs in browser result in different sessions for server?

Tags: firefox, session

If I open a connection to the server from firefox browser, and then I open a new tab within the same instance of browser to make a connection to the server, is it considered one session to server or considered as two diff sessions?

Answer (score 2):

It's the same session (you can easily test this out yourself).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the same session.
However, if I use diff user to login, both seems to be categorized under same session? Is this the correct behaviour?

Comment: surely it depends on what you're logging in to and what authentication mechanism it uses?

Comment: we use LDAP authentication, but it's a J2EE application running on Weblogic. I tested it IE, no problem (it's two diff sessions). I did test on cross browser (IE and Firefox), it's no problem as well. But when I use firefox to connect to server using two diff userid, the session is the same. why?

Answer (score 0):

If you click a link on the current session to open it up in a new tab, then it'sthe same session.  If you just open up a blank window and log in again, then, to the best of my knowledge,it's a new session.